# How to recover data after lvremove in centos 7.0?

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, fdisk, lvm

I did a stupid thing by removing a Logic volume by issuing the below command.

```
lvremove -f /dev/cl_dhcppc4/home
```

However, immediately I restored the lvm from the backup file.

```
vgcfgrestore --file /etc/lvm/archive/cl_dhcppc4_00001-1231497433.vg cl_dhcppc4
```

But I could not mount this logic volume and access the data in it. I can able to see the lvm and repective fdisk.Results below.

```
[root@localhost lk]# lvdisplay -m
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl_dhcppc4/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                cl_dhcppc4
  LV UUID                d0JfQW-CmGW-9gC8-C3I9-HH0c-x3EA-ZRu3qT
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time dhcppc4, 2016-05-16 10:43:13 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                7.75 GiB
  Current LE             1984
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 1983:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda2
    Physical extents    0 to 1983


  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl_dhcppc4/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                cl_dhcppc4
  LV UUID                r1OcXu-JpSL-1pv5-oDPw-k9Q3-3ioS-hIeDnb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time dhcppc4, 2016-05-16 10:43:13 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                873.21 GiB
  Current LE             223541
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 223540:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda2
    Physical extents    1984 to 225524


  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl_dhcppc4/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                cl_dhcppc4
  LV UUID                MZTJcW-909k-cyjf-e3ls-K8hl-lYNm-Gk97kA
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time dhcppc4, 2016-05-16 10:43:16 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 12799:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda2
    Physical extents    225525 to 238324
```

I need to recover the data from LV Path /dev/cl_dhcppc4/home. Fdisk give me below result.

```
[root@localhost lk]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000e45e4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2   *     1026048  1953523711   976248832   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/cl_dhcppc4-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl_dhcppc4-swap: 8321 MB, 8321499136 bytes, 16252928 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl_dhcppc4-home: 937.6 GB, 937598910464 bytes, 1831247872 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

If I try to mount the disk, it is giving file system type errors for nfs, ext3 file types.

```
[root@localhost lk]# mount /dev/mapper/cl_dhcppc4-home /hd
mount: /dev/mapper/cl_dhcppc4-home is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: unknown filesystem type '(null)'

[root@localhost lk]# mount -t nfs /dev/mapper/cl_dhcppc4-home /hd
mount.nfs: remote share not in 'host:dir' format

[root@localhost lk]# mount -t ext3 /dev/mapper/cl_dhcppc4-home /hd
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/cl_dhcppc4-home,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Please help to recover the data from this mess. I had some important data in this disk.

Comment: Are you using a SSD? What is the value of `issue_discards` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`?

Comment: @Bigon I am using HDD. This is a desktop computer for personal use.`     issue_discards = 0`. Thanks.

Comment: @Bigon ` issue_discards = 0`

Comment: The data should still be there then. Did you changed the LVM topology between the delete and the call to vgcfgrestore? What is `sudo lsblk -f` telling you?

Comment: @Bigon lsblk is not showing the FSTYPE and UUID for the affected file system. I have given details in the answer. Thanks lot for your time,,,

Answer (score 0):

@Bigon To retrieve the data I tried myself and issued few commands which might have changed the LVM topology. My histroy between lvremove and vgcfgrestore are  below. Commnad 86 removed the LVM and command 153 is correctly retrieved. But in between I created few lvm and deleted them as well.

```
86  lvremove -f /dev/cl_dhcppc4/home
   87  lvscan
   88  lvremove -f /dev/cl_dhcppc4/home
   89  fdisk -l
   90  mount /dev/sda2 /dev/sda2
   91  lvscan
   92  mount
   94  lvdisplay cl_dhcppc4
  100  lvcreate --extents EFROM-ETO --zero n --name customer007 YOUR-VG-NAME /dev/yourpv:PFROM-PTO
  101  lvcreate --extents EFROM-ETO --zero n --name test007 test007   /dev/sda2:PFROM-PTO
  102  lvcreate --help
  103  lvcreate /dev/sda2
  104  fdisk -l
  105  pvs
  106  lvdisplay cl_dhcppc4
  110  lvdisplay
  111  dmsetup ls
  112  dmsetup table cl_dhcppc4-home
  113  dmsetup table cl_dhcppc4-root
  116  pvcreate /dev/sda2
  117  pvcreate -ff  /dev/sda2
  118  vgcreate vgpool /dev/sda2
  119  pvcreate -ff  /dev/sda2
  120  pvs
  121  sh /etc/rd.d/rc.lvm2 start
  122  vgscan
  123  vgchange --available n
  124  lvcreate -L 3G -n cl_dhcppc4 vgpool
  125  lvcreate -L 3G -n lvstuff cl_dhcppc4
  129  lvcreate -l 20 -n logical_vol1 cl_dhcppc4 
  130  lvdisplay
  131  lvremove /dev/cl_dhcppc4/lvstuff
  132  lvremove /dev/cl_dhcppc4/logical_vol1
  152  vgcfgrestore –file /etc/lvm/archive/cl_dhcppc4_00001-1231497433.vg
  153  vgcfgrestore –file /etc/lvm/archive/cl_dhcppc4_00001-1231497433.vg cl_dhcppc4
```

lsblk is not showing the FSTYPE and UUID for the affected file system cl_dhcppc4-home.

```
 [root@localhost lk]# lsblk -f
NAME                FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                          
├─sda1              xfs               acc94e95-aff5-44dc-acd6-e53ab9b85970   
└─sda2              LVM2_member       V3EMqc-bTyq-v8fz-vZfU-bUvv-torq-lEitpO 
  ├─cl_dhcppc4-root xfs               6d107d35-4ba3-4f08-97ca-ac33338cf97c   /
  ├─cl_dhcppc4-swap swap              f452dcca-9254-42e4-bee6-dc9c760ade58   
  └─cl_dhcppc4-home                                                          
sr0
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't smells good to me. I don't think the FS is still usable here. You'll probably need to recover the data an other way, maybe have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery